# jQuery Radio Button Click

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with radio button click event via jQuery 11.1. If I click on div the radio button state change to clicked at first time but I click again and again than its not working.
Here is my code HTML code

```
<section class="selection-box">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="selection-box-title">Brand</div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix selected brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Desktop </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Mac </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Here is jQuery code

```
<script>
$(".brandSection").click(function () {

  $('input[type="radio"]', this).attr('checked', 'checked');

  if ($('input[type="radio"]', this).attr('checked', 'checked') == true) {
    $('brandSection').removeClass('selected');

  }
  else {
    $('.brandSection').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

  }


});
```

Any tweaks I missed on that?

Comment: One thing I'm absolutely certain of is that you are not using jQuery version 11.1 (version 3.1 is, I think, the latest version available as I write this). Did you mean 1.11.1 by any chance? And let's assume we, the users of SO, have no idea what your code is meant to be doing. Could you explain it to us, in the simplest, clearest way possible, what your code should do. In response to what?

Comment: The radio buttons should not have the same id. JavaScript only reacts on the first instance of the id.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```js
$(".brandSection").click(function () {
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);

    $('.brandSection').removeClass('selected'); // duplicate lines
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // not understanding for this line
    // why you add class selected when the radio button is NOT clicked?
     
});
```

```css
.selected {
    border: 1px solid #00f
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="selection-box">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="selection-box-title">Brand</div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix selected brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio1" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Desktop </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio2" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Mac </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want the brandSection to have a class selected, you can add a line of code under the `$('.brandSection').removeClass('selected');` `$(this).addClass('selected');`

Comment: Thanks. Its working. but I want to add selected class clicked radio button div brandSection. Is that possible.

Comment: @JohnAbraham Check for my update. `$('.brandSection').removeClass('selected');` would remove class `selected` from all `div.brandSection`. `$(this).addClass('selected');` would add class `selected` to current div

Comment: @KevinOrfas ya. OP is putting it in the wrong place. I've just edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo at the class `brandSection`:

```
if ($('input[type="radio"]', this).attr('checked', 'checked') == true) {
    $('.brandSection').removeClass('selected');

  }
```

Better wrap your code in document ready statement

```
$(function(){
//your code here
})
```

Select the input relative to the current clicked element using `find()`

Comment: Ohh my bad! but still does not work, if I clicked on div. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, based on some small guesses as to what you want to happen in your code:

```js
// binding the anonymous function of the click() method
// as the event-handler for the click event:
$(".brandSection").click(function() {

  // finding the descendant radio input (using
  // plain JavaScript in this case since it's
  // faster/cheaper than calling jQuery:
  var radio = this.querySelector('input[type=radio]');

  // setting the checked property to (Boolean) true:
  radio.checked = true;

  // adding the 'selected' class-name to the clicked
  // .brandSelection element:
  $(this).addClass('selected')
    // selecting the siblings of that element:
    .siblings()
    // and removing the 'selected' class from those elements
    // (to ensure only one element is selected):
    .removeClass('selected');

// filtering the collection of '.brandSection' elements to
// find the one - if any - with the 'selected' class-name:
}).filter('.selected')
// triggering the 'click' event on that element, in order
// that the appropriate radio-input shows up as selected
// on page-load:
.click();
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="selection-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="selection-box-title">Brand</div>
      <div class="radioStyle clearfix selected brandSection">
        <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio" />
        <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
          <span class="col-lg-6">Desktop </span>
          <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
        <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio" />
        <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
          <span class="col-lg-6">Mac</span>
          <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
        </label>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c2q4ut1o/).

The error in your original code was the line:

```
$('input[type="radio"]', this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

The `checked` attribute doesn't – unfortunately – update the `checked` property.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click).

Comment: I'm happy to have helped! Bear in mind that if one of the answers to your question solved your problem you can up-vote that, or those, answers and accept the answer that best helped you (whether this answer or any other, it's entirely your choice). If, however, we merely pointed you to a solution and you solved your problem in a different way please consider posting your own answer to show your solution and then, when you're able, you can accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop('checked', true)` instead.

```js
$(".brandSection").click(function () {
  $('input[name="brandRadio"]', this).prop('checked', true);
  $(".brandSection").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="selection-box">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="selection-box-title">Brand</div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Desktop </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
      <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" type="radio">
      <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
        <span class="col-lg-6">Mac </span>
        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
      </label>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using same ID for both radio button. Element ID should be always unique. 
Secondly correct `$('brandSection')` to`$('.brandSection')`

Please use following:

```
$(".brandSection").click(function () {

   var radButton = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
   $('.brandSection').removeClass('selected');
   $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
   $(radButton).attr('checked', 'checked');
   $(radButton).addClass('selected');

});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6yyr4v/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more line to have the brandSection with the class by using $(this).

```
$(".brandSection").click(function () {
        $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);

        $('.brandSection').removeClass('selected'); 
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```